# How to scrape content from a div class based on data-automation attribute in Python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a dynamic page using BeautifulSoup. After accessing the said page from https://www.nemlig.com/ with the help of Selenium (and thanks to the code advice from @cruisepandey) like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\lib\chromedriver_77.0.3865.40.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.nemlig.com/")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".timeslot-prompt.initial-animation-done")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='tel'][class^='pro']"))).send_keys('2300')  
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.prompt__button"))).click()
```

I am prompted with this page that I want to scrape.

[image]

More precisely, at this point, I want to scrape the rows from the right-hand side of the page. If you look through the HTML code behind these you will notice that the div class `time-block__row` has 3 different data-automation attributes for the main 3 times of the day.

```
<div class="time-block__row" data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt">
                            <div class="time-block__row-header">Formiddag</div>

                            <div class="no-timeslots ng-hide" ng-show="$ctrl.timeslotDays[$ctrl.selectedDateIndex].morningHours == 0">
                                Ingen levering..
                            </div>

                            <!----><!----><div class="time-block__item duration-1 disabled" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.selectedHours track by $index" ng-if="item.StartHour >= 0 &amp;&amp; item.StartHour < 12" ng-click="$ctrl.setActiveTimeslot(item, $index)" ng-class="['duration-1', {'cheapest': item.IsCheapHour, 'event': item.IsEventSlot, 'selected': $ctrl.selectedTimeId == item.Id || $ctrl.selectedTimeIndex == $index, 'disabled': item.isUnavailable()}]" data-automation="notActiveSltTmSlt">

                                <div class="time-block__inner-container">
                <div class="time-block__time">8-9</div>
                <div class="time-block__attributes">
                  <!----></div>
                                    <div class="time-block__cost">29&nbsp;kr.</div>
```

So *Formiddag* (Morning) has `data-automation = "beforDinnerRowTmSlt"`, *Eftermiddag* (Afternoon) has `data-automation = "afternoonRowTmSlt"` and *Aften* (Evening) has `data-automation = "eveningRowTmSlt"`.

```
page_source = wait.until(driver.page_source)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
   
time_of_the_day = soup.find('div', class_='time-block__row').text
```

- The problem is

using the code above, `time_of_the_day` only contains information from the Morning rows.

How can I scrape these rows properly using the `data-automation` attribute? How can I possibly access the other 2 div classes and their child divs? My plan is to create a dataframe containing something like this:

```
Time_of_the_day          Hours          Price        Day
Formiddag                8-9            29kr.        Tor. 10/10
....                     ....           ....         ....
Eftermiddag              12-13          29kr.        Tor. 10/10
....                     ....           ....         ....
```

The `day` column will contain the output from here: `day = soup.find('div', class_='content').text`

I know this is quite a lengthy post but hopefully I've made it easy to understand the task and you will be able to help me out with advice, tips or code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code to get all those values.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\lib\chromedriver_77.0.3865.40.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.nemlig.com/")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".timeslot-prompt.initial-animation-done")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='tel'][class^='pro']"))).send_keys('2300')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.prompt__button"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
time_of_day=[]
price=[]
Hours=[]
day=[]
for morn in soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'):
    time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
    Hours.append(morn.text)
    price.append(morn.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
    day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"time_of_day":time_of_day,"Hours":Hours,"price":price,"Day":day})
print(df)

time_of_day=[]
price=[]
Hours=[]
day=[]

for after in soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'):
    time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
    Hours.append(after.text)
    price.append(after.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
    day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"time_of_day":time_of_day,"Hours":Hours,"price":price,"Day":day})
print(df)

time_of_day=[]
price=[]
Hours=[]
day=[]

for evenin in soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'):
    time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
    Hours.append(evenin.text)
    price.append(evenin.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
    day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"time_of_day":time_of_day,"Hours":Hours,"price":price,"Day":day})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Day  Hours   price time_of_day
0  fre. 11/10    8-9  29 kr.   Formiddag
1  fre. 11/10   9-10  29 kr.   Formiddag
2  fre. 11/10  10-11  39 kr.   Formiddag
3  fre. 11/10  11-12  39 kr.   Formiddag
          Day  Hours   price  time_of_day
0  fre. 11/10  12-13  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
1  fre. 11/10  13-14  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
2  fre. 11/10  14-15  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
3  fre. 11/10  15-16  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
4  fre. 11/10  16-17  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
5  fre. 11/10  17-18  19 kr.  Eftermiddag
          Day  Hours   price time_of_day
0  fre. 11/10  18-19  29 kr.       Aften
1  fre. 11/10  19-20  19 kr.       Aften
2  fre. 11/10  20-21  29 kr.       Aften
3  fre. 11/10  21-22  19 kr.       Aften
```

---

**Edited**

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
time_of_day=[]
price=[]
Hours=[]
day=[]
disabled=[]

for morn,d in zip(soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'),soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__item')):

    time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="beforDinnerRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
    Hours.append(morn.text)
    price.append(morn.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
    day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)
    if 'disabled' in d['class']:
        disabled.append('1')
    else:
        disabled.append('0')

for after,d in zip(soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'),soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__item')):
    time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="afternoonRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
    Hours.append(after.text)
    price.append(after.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
    day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)
    if 'disabled' in d['class']:
        disabled.append('1')
    else:
        disabled.append('0')

for evenin,d in zip(soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__time'),soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"]').select('.time-block__item')):
    time_of_day.append(soup.select_one('[data-automation="eveningRowTmSlt"] > .time-block__row-header').text)
    Hours.append(evenin.text)
    price.append(evenin.find_next(class_="time-block__cost").text)
    day.append(soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayNmTmSlt"]').text + " " + soup.select_one('.date-block.selected [data-automation="dayDateTmSlt"]').text)
    if 'disabled' in d['class']:
        disabled.append('1')
    else:
        disabled.append('0')

df = pd.DataFrame({"time_of_day":time_of_day,"Hours":Hours,"price":price,"Day":day,"Disabled" : disabled})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
           Day Disabled  Hours   price  time_of_day
0   fre. 11/10        1    8-9  29 kr.    Formiddag
1   fre. 11/10        1   9-10  29 kr.    Formiddag
2   fre. 11/10        0  10-11  39 kr.    Formiddag
3   fre. 11/10        0  11-12  39 kr.    Formiddag
4   fre. 11/10        0  12-13  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
5   fre. 11/10        0  13-14  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
6   fre. 11/10        0  14-15  19 kr.  Eftermiddag
7   fre. 11/10        0  15-16  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
8   fre. 11/10        0  16-17  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
9   fre. 11/10        0  17-18  29 kr.  Eftermiddag
10  fre. 11/10        0  18-19  29 kr.        Aften
11  fre. 11/10        0  19-20  19 kr.        Aften
12  fre. 11/10        0  20-21  29 kr.        Aften
13  fre. 11/10        0  21-22  19 kr.        Aften
```

Comment: You can do it on single data frame as well if you are looking after that let me know

Comment: I can not thank you enough for your help with all of this! Too bad I can give you an upvote only once... As for the dataframes, I was looking for only 1 dataframe containing all of them, indeed. I would assume that I will have to use something like `pd.append` in order to achieve that?

Comment: Give me an hour I am outside now.No need to append.If you keep only first declare array and remove all array and dataframe and keep only last dataframe you will get that.if not possible to you I will come back an hour

Comment: One more thing - tell me if you can answer here or I should post another question - is that I thought of adding a new column for when the `hours...price` is disabled and the div class name is `time-block__item duration-1 disabled`. Do you have any tips on how to also achieve that? A column with 0 or 1 depending if it's disabled or not.

Comment: I added this: `if soup.select_one('[class="time-block__item duration-1 disabled"]').text:
        ok = 1
    else:
        ok = 0` at the end of the for loops but then everything gets set to 1. Please let me know if you have any suggestions, when you have time :).

Comment: @Questieme : Updated the code with disabled options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `soup.find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
... #rest of your current selenium code

d = soup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
r, _day = [[i.div.text, [['disabled' in k['class'], k.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('time-block__time|ime-block__cost')})] for k in i.find_all('div', {'class':'time-block__item'})]] for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':'time-block__row'})], d.find('div', {'class':'content'}).get_text(strip=True)
new_r = [[a, [[int(j), *[i.text for i in b]] for j, b in k]] for a, k in r]
new_data = [[a, *i, _day] for a, b in new_r for i in b]
```

---

To convert your results to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(['Time_of_the_day', 'Disabled', 'Hours', 'Price', 'Day'], i)) for i in new_data])
```

Output:

```
      Day  Disabled  Hours   Price Time_of_the_day
0   fre.11/10         1    8-9  29 kr.       Formiddag
1   fre.11/10         1   9-10  29 kr.       Formiddag
2   fre.11/10         1  10-11  39 kr.       Formiddag
3   fre.11/10         0  11-12  39 kr.       Formiddag
4   fre.11/10         0  12-13  29 kr.     Eftermiddag
....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! As I also asked @KunduK in his answer, I might have another problem related to this. `Tell me if you can answer here or I should post another question - is that I thought of adding a new column for when the hours...price is disabled and the div class name is time-block__item duration-1 disabled. Do you have any tips on how to also achieve that? A column with 0 or 1 depending if it's disabled or not.`